# FullCalendar not deleting events

Tags: jquery, web, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar in a web page, and I've implemented a lot of features on it. Now, I'm trying to delete all the events from a specific month, but something strange is happening.

The way I'm deleting my events is like this:

```
$(calendario).fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(evt){
                                        var fechaEvt = new Date(evt.start);
                                        return (fechaEvt.getMonth()   === month &&
                                               fechaEvt.getFullYear() === year &&
                                               idsPunto.indexOf(evt.idPunto) !== -1 )
                                });
```

If I print `$(calendario).fullCalendar('clientEvents')` before and after the code shown before, it shows first an array with 11 elements, and then an empty array, so it seems that they are gone. Actually, you can see the calendar being empty for 0.5 seconds, but then, all the events are shown again.

The strange thing here is that, if I delete manually less than 11 events it works fine, but If I try to delete ALL my events, happends the thing I said before.

I've tried different algorithms (like deleting 1 by 1), but nothing works

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this with `php` and `yii2` - I don't see any PHP code.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I'm using yii2 and php, but that isn't shown in the code, I'll delete those tags

Comment: "but then, all the events are shown again." Is your calendar auto-updating from the server on a set interval, perhaps? It sounds like an odd problem. Can you make a working example to demonstrate the issue, using JSFiddle or Codepen? Something clearly is interfering with it.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it could be something like that... I can delete events 1 by 1 (clicking an event opens a modal, and there I can delete it). If I do that with all my events, it works fine... probably I'm missing something. I'll keep trying, but if I get stuck again, I'll try to upload a JSFiddle, thanks